# Delete Objects From Parse/ Cannot cast to PFObject/ NSArrayM

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

My problem is:
I am querying `user["key"]` that I am attempting to assign to a new variable, as on the documentation.

The column in Parse is an array of `Strings`, in my query, if I `println(user["key"])` it returns the correct objects.

However, when I do:

```
let myVariable = user["key"] as String
```

or

```
let myVariable = user["key"] as! String
```

I have the error:

> Could not cast a value of type _NSArrayM to NSString

My end goal is to retrieve objects from Parse, and submit an "if" condition and then delete the results. For this I need to convert the objects into `PFObject` and this is where I struggle.

To add, I can only downcast to `AnyObject!`  from `let myVariable = user["key"]`

and when I try to delete this object, I have the error

> NSArrayM delete: unrecognised selector sent to instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First you say "The column in Parse is an array of Strings", then you try `as String`, what a surprise that is not working, you should maybe use `[String]`

Comment: Indeed, Thanks a lot. I got confused as my objects in Parse were themselves arrays. I do admit that the mistake was silly. Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com normally return an array, as you can see in your error message:

> Could not cast a value of type _NSArrayM to NSString

`__NSArrayM` is a code-word for a mutable array, so you are trying to cast an array to a string.

If you are sure your query is return just one result you can retrieve just the last (and only) element in the array and cast to string.

```
if let myVariable = user["key"].last as? String{
    println("myVariable key is \(myVariable)"
} else { 
    println("Could not retrieve key") 
}
```

Comment: I think you have an extra `?`.  I don't have Xcode open... but shouldn't it just be `user["key"].last as? String`?

Comment: @nhgrif You are correct, I was thinking because the array could be empty it would be an optional but I test in XCode and the compiler ask me to delete. I already fix the code above. Thanks

Comment: You *are* correct.  The array could be empty and `last` could return `nil`, but the `?` is unnecessary here anyway.

Comment: @viktor I am glad that helped you, please don't forget to check the issue as solved if it is fixed now, and good luck with your app!

Comment: @Icaro, everything solved and fine. Aside this slight mistake, I actually had the identical column in Parse being constantly added with objects as I was trying to modify them. I therefore had to stop the addition of objects before applying the modification. And while trying a considerable number of solutions without having actually identify the exact source of my problem, I got lost in the casting of my objects and so on. I had to take a good step back from the project, a bit of sleep and a game of tennis, and then fresh mind good to go. But thanks a million for your help and for the wishes.

Comment: @viktor Sometimes a break is all we need. Are you able to check the green box next to the question so it is marked as resolved, otherwise other people may try to answer it too!